# Java stream with equal, always returning null

Tags: java, java-stream, equals

Additional question about my last problem..

```
    BigDecimal fee;

    fee = fees.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTodate().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getFromdate().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .filter(p -> p.getId().equals("001001"))
            .map(Fee::getFee)
            .findFirst()
            .map(BigDecimal::new)
            .orElse(new BigDecimal(1000));

    return fee;
```

I first check that the fee is up to date, as there might be upcoming fees and fees that are no longer valid. Then I try to match the id with remaining fees.

The problem is the last filter.
i've checked multiple times and in data, there is exactly 1 entry with current date and this very same id. (it was input before but for debugging purposes i've hardcoded it for now)

and if i take date filters off this will still only return BigDecimal 1000.

What am i not seeing here?

Both values are `Strings`

Comment: maybe getFee returns an empty list. You should try the result with just the filters to see if the issue is really on the filter behaviour...

Comment: @snap done that, data is coming through just fine

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of the class Fee?

Comment: @csalmhof if it's simple entity, there's nothing interesting there. what you want to see?

Comment: so, there is a result after filtering?

Comment: can you please show results of the operations, step by step? what happens with only first filter, second, after third, after map, after find first and after else :) this will also help you

Comment: maybe there is an unseen char in the saved Id from input? do both Strings have the same length?

Comment: I guess getId() must be the culprit due to String mismatch, maybe due to length

Comment: just  a guess, maybe .map(Fee::getFee) return empty result, which would then make it so you get "no result" in the map, which would then throw you into else block?

Comment: can you juste provide a exemple Code as https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec what are you missing? As far as I can tell, all the info you need is in the question, except maybe intermediate result

Comment: btw, does findAny() changes anything in result, instead of findFirst?

Comment: @Sarief fees sample definition ? Fee class?

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec and why would you need it? you can deduct those values fromthe code he has shown. toDate, fromDate, id, fee (integer)

Comment: to provide a runnable code to handle your issue .... 45 people read your post none have answer beacause we can t solve your issue without testing it to understand what really happen in your code that make it fail. the issue is clearly not directly in your snippet

Comment: its an issue in fees content or in getFee methods all the rest of the code can't produce the result that you describe

Comment: You can add `.peek(System.out::println)` at different points to we what, if any, values are in the stream.

Comment: This definitively requires a [mcve].

Comment: `new BigDecimal(1000)` is an unusual fall-back value in that it is impossible to distinguish it from the scenario where `Fee::getFee` just returned `"1000"`. So who says that the result of `1000` is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..

Not really an answer but i ran out of time and did the exact same thing
with regular old for loop, and everything went just as expected and worked just fine...

So i will still not use streams going forward..

EDIT:
code

```
for(Fee fee : fees){
    if(fee.getId.equals(id)){
        if(fee.getFromdate().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())){
            if(fee.getTodate().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now())){
                BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(fee.getFundservicefee());
                return z.movePointLeft(2);
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please include the code that was used to fix the problem in case anyone has a similar issue in the future.